# Smartest way to set color for enabled/disabled buttons with SwiftUI

Tags: button, swiftui

I'd like to set the color of a Text view inside a Button view based on whether the button is enabled or disabled. What is the smartest way to do this and also to get the system default colors for enabled/disabled colors, because I don't want to set any gray shade, I'd like to set the "normal" gray shade.

Comment: I found two blogs here ( https://alejandromp.com ) to be very helpful for this. While they are almost a month old, they should help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, adding `.buttonStyle(.plain)` to the button just did what I was looking for. Now, the button automatically gets a gray color if it's disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it in SwiftUI 2.0

```
Button("PressME", action: {self.playerAttemptCount += 1
                           }).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

This way, the button automatically gets a gray color if it is disabled.